# Extra line is appearing for no reason after my first scanf?

Tags: c

```
printf("Input A: ");
scanf("%f\n",&A);
printf("Input B: ");
scanf("%f\n",&B);
printf("Input C: ");
scanf("%f\n",&C);
```

When I go to run this I can enter an A value but then another blank line appears with nothing written on it and i have to input something which isnt saved into any varible or anything. Even if I comment out the first printf and scanf, the same thing happens with B. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Do not put the `\n` in `scanf` format string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a space before the `%f` in each format:

```
printf("Input A: ");
scanf(" %f",&A);
printf("Input B: ");
scanf(" %f",&B);
printf("Input C: ");
scanf(" %f",&C);
```